# I an having a problem using immediate: true in a watch in nuxt 2.00. I am getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, watch

Hi I have a basic computed property and a watch which works fine see below

```js
  computed: {
    loadedLessonsChange() {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedLessonsChange;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    loadedLessonsChange() {
      console.log("watch changed");
    },
  },
```

Now I want to use  "immediate: true" so it happens on page load as well as change so I followed the examples and changed the watch to this

```js
watch: {
    loadedLessonsChange: {
      immediate: true,
      MyloadedLessonsChange() {
        console.log("watch changed");
      },
    },
  },
```

but what ever I do I get this error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply'). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `apply` is located on an async object I guess? Are you sure that it's available straight when you try to watch it?

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when a [`watch` object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) is missing its `handler` property. You've incorrectly named the callback as `"MyloadedLessonsChange"`.

The solution is to rename that to `"handler"`:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    loadedLessonsChange: {
      immediate: true,

      ❌ must be named "handler"
      // MyloadedLessonsChange() { /*...*/ }

      ✅
      handler() { /*...*/ },
    },
  },
}
```